# Add product description (content) to WooCommerce customer processing order email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm looking for a way to add the product description (content) to the WooCommerce customer processing order email, as it contains important information to pass to the customer that they need for their records.

I presume I need to edit the template at WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > Processing Order, but what line and what with?

Does anyone have any cut and paste code?

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<h2><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></h2>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), true, $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code in your functions.php file of your current theme

```
function render_product_description($item_id, $item, $order){
    $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
    echo "<br>" . $_product->post->post_content; 

}

add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'render_product_description',10,3);
```

Comment: This was really useful, but if you also want it to be formatted, make sure to use the filter for the content. `echo "<br>" . apply_filters('the_content', $_product->post->post_content);`